# software to dial a number every 20 minutes via sip

Tags: sip, voip, phone-call

I am looking to find a software that calls via sip every 20 minutes. Actually i want to to call a specific number but the line drops after 20 minutes. I want to redial automatically when the line has dropped....Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Voxeo Prophecy](http://www.voxeo.com/products/voicexml-ivr-platform.jsp) with [Call Control XML (CCXML)](http://www.w3.org/TR/ccxml/) to achieve these requirements.  Prophecy uses SIP as its telecommunications interface, and with CCXML you can easily make outbound calls and perform call progress analysis to determine if a line is dropped. You can download a free copy of Prophecy that has two ports and can be run on a local server or you can use their hosted service. The hosted service will allow you to test this out for free and pay if you put it into production. The tech support guys at Voxeo are extremely helpful and there is documentation on their site for how to make outbound calls and perform call progress analysis.